# What to do if pip for Python 2.7 can't be installed from the command prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I need to install pip for Python 2.7 (Some crucial software (ArcGIS 10.2) on my computer runs on Python 2.7.3, so that is the version I need; upgrading to a newer version is not an option.) I open the command prompt as an administrator, change the working directory to the Scripts folder under where Python 2.7 is installed and run the following command:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
```

What seems like the whole contents of that file appear on the screen, and then I type in `py get-pip.py`. This does nothing but launch the Microsoft Store app for downloading (the latest version of) Python. I tried doing it differently, saving the contents of https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py as a .py file in the Scripts folder and running that file, but the result is the same. What is going on here? Is it because pip for Python 2.7 is deprecated? Also, for some reason, the command prompt does not recognize the Python command, saying that it was not found. Using `py` instead launches Microsoft Store.

Comment: You have to add `-o` option to `curl`. Otherwise, it just prints the contents on the screen. Eg, `curl -o get-pip.py https://...`

Comment: "**Also, for some reason, the command prompt does not recognize the Python command, saying that it was not found.**" I would focus on getting this resolved first. Then worry about `pip`.

Comment: I agree with @InnocentBystander pip should probably come bundled with the python version that you have. The fact that you cannot run python from your `cmd` indicates that you have not added it to `PATH` correctly. Once you get that fixed, you will probably notice that you already can launch pip